# How to access a state function outside async await useEffect

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to set function and acess outside useEffect. but I am no not getting value

Here is my code

```
 const [emailOwner, setEmailOwner] = React.useState("");
        
    useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
    let params = localStorage;
    let queryId1 = params.getItem("queryId1");
    let queryId2 = params.getItem("queryId2");
    let queryId3 = params.getItem("queryId3");
    let res = await axios.get(
    `localhost:3000/users?id1=${queryId1}&id2=${queryId2}&id3=${queryId3}`
    );
    setmessage(
    `Thello`
    );
    setoneUrl(
    `hello2`
    );
    setlastUrl(
    `\nhello3`
    );
    console.log('response', res.data);
    setEmailOwner(res.data);
    }
    getData();
    }, []);
```

Here I can see `res.data` in console. but if I `setEmailOwner` inside useEffect  not able to access value outside if I call it as `emailOwner` . Kindly help .

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Is the query about inability to access `getData()` outside `useEffect`??

Comment: no errors , I am not able to access `setEmailOwner` outside `useEffect`. value is empty. if i try to print `console.log(emailOwner) ` outside `useEffect`

Comment: The effect runs asynchronously and the value will be unavailable untill the promise resolves. I think your issue is trying the access the value before it's set

Comment: Any way to access the `res.data` result outside useeffect?